# Raphael JS: wrong position after scale path in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, raphael

I have problems with scaling a path in internet explorer, because it results in a wrong position.

Here an example for the playground, check it out in FF and IE:

```
paper.path("m40,40 h10 v10 h-10 v-10").transform("s8");
```

I tried this in Raphael playground and also here: http://jsfiddle.net/M4Rmm/.

Works in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE the path is moved and has the wrong position. Doesn't matter if I use the `.scale()` or `.transform()` function.

```
paper.path("m40,40 h10 v10 h-10 v-10").scale(8,8); //same result like .transform("s8");
```

My system: Win7, x64 / FF10, IE8 / Raphael 2.x

I also tried new Raphael version 2.1.0, but the same problem occurs.

Any ideas, how to solve this problem?

Comment: My colleague found the possible problem in the Raphael code at line 5317 and raplaced "matrix.translate(-.5, -.5);" with"matrix.translate(1, 1);".

This works and the paths are positioned correct!

Comment: My colleague already sent it to him, but no reaction until now...
But I created an issue at github: 
https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/issues/653

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in the history (2.1.1 • 2013-08-11, 4th point), this bug is fixed now with the new version!
https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/blob/master/history.md

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue whith positioning in IE, I hade two arcs (I used a simplyfied version of the raphael polar-clock arc function). But the positioning were off in IE.

I changed the matrix.translate as Chris suggested and that solved my problem.

Thanks